# if $f(x)=x^2-2$ then real solutions of $f^n(x)=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recurrence-relations, contest-math

> if $f(x)=x^2-2$ where $x\in[-2,2]$ then find the number of real solutions $f^n(x)=x$  for some natural $n$ where $f^n(x)=f(f^{n-1}(x))$

I had no clue on how to start , a recurrence relation seemed unobvious.Hence i started with examples!

$f(x)=x\Rightarrow x^2-x-2=0$ has two solutions.

Now $f(f(x))=x\Rightarrow x^4-4x^2-x+2=(x-2)(x+1)(x^2+x-1)=0$ has $4$ solutions.

By the time it reached $f(f(f(x)))=x$ i lost my patience.I hence went to WA which says that there are 8 roots.I see the pattern it looks like number of roots is $2^n$......

Any hints??

I would love a solution without calculus but i am ok with it otherwise..

Comment: Solutions are $2^n$. All real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$f(2\cos x) = 4\cos^2 x - 2 = 2\cos 2x$$

hence

$$f^{\circ n}(2\cos x) = 2\cos 2^n x$$

Comment: What if there are other solutions?

Comment: @Buraian based on how fast the function $f^{\circ n}(x)$ grows for large negative and positive $x$, you should be able to show that the zeroes are confined to a small interval containing the origin.